# Hint on making UI as shown in the video

Tags: android, material-design

Can anyone guide me on making UI as shown in the video. I have Googled for various library but so far they only support one scrollable view i.e. it can't support for two scrollable views as shown in the video. Any expert guidance would help me a lot. Here is the video link
[Material Profile Design](http://youtu.be/i-RlAsJ5qUw)

Basically the view is like this

- It contains two scrollable items (one at header and other at body)
- When body is scrolled up, then header gradually disappears like parallax effect seen on `Actionbar/Toolbar`
- When body is scrolled down, the header gradually appears and eventually when we scroll more the header view now takes the whole view and scrolls like a list view downwards.
- When back button is pressed, the header will scroll up and only one item of header will be shown with body covering entire view

  To be frank, explaining the view on words is very hard and for that purpose I have uploaded a video of it. So watching the video, one could easily understand the UI. So far I have found this resource that seems helpful [Sliding Up Layout With MapView](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=915)

Answer (score 1):

It will be a very complex layout to create but this is one way of doing it.

First, start by examining (and fully understanding) this code:

https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar

The part that should be of most interest is that

1. Everything is in a list view. This includes the header too!
2. A "fake header" is used in order to limit the navigation upward

Once you have an understanding of how the code works, you can start working on your layout.

How I would then start doing this would be to implement the above code but removing the `min(header)` logic which prevents the scrolling up. Instead, I would intercept that code and once the layout has been scrolled to the very top, I would start adding images to the list view at index 0 dynamically so that they would appear above the header. I would also make sure I scroll to index 0 whenever I'm adding a new item.

This way, the transition down would still work (thanks to the code I linked to) with the fancy scaling bitmap and varying height "header", and transitioning up would also allow me to add items when the user is scrolling up.

Having said all these, I really dislike that layout. It's not conventional and will look extremely confusing to your users. Not many people would know they can scroll up and for you, as a programmer, handling not only going up (to show your images above the header) but also going down (to go back to your original layout) will be very painful.

Comment: Thanks @kha, I will take a look at this and follow your guidelines and lets see how far can I go. Thanks again